# How to extract linked images out of a html page with PHP/regexp

Tags: php, html, regex, image, extract

I'm looking for some PHP code or a rexeg expression (i'm not that skilled about regexp) to extract from a html file just the linked images. In other words, just the chunk of html that looks like:

```
<a href=...><img src=...></a>
```

I know how to extract images and links separately

```
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

but not how to extract the two tags one inside the other. I have also not found anything by googling it. So is it maybe uncommon or very difficult what I want to do?

Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: I don't use any, currently. I have just the list of the links and the list of the images and i just need a combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following XPath query:

```
//a[./img]
```

which means any `<a>` element which has a `<img>` as its direct child.

Using [PHP's DOM API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), this would look like this:

```
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$imageLinks = $xpath->query('//a[./img]');
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/GXAbC**

If the image can be further down the DOM tree, you can change the XPath query to this:

```
//a[.//img]
```

Comment: I think OP just wants the image, but this is definitely the right way to do it.

Comment: I considered the "just the chunk of html that looks like" part of the question, but you may be right, in which case I'll edit the answer with `//a/img`. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say. But I think your interpretation is more likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solution **without** `xpath` can be:

```
$links = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $img = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');
    // getting first element of DOMNodeList
    print_r($img->item(0));
}
```